# CURL JSESSIONID problem

Tags: javascript, jsp, cookies, curl

I have some issues getting a web page using CURL.
I think the reason is that my CURL request does not include the JSESSIONID value.

This is how my cookie file looks like at the end:

```
direct.orange.co.il FALSE   /   FALSE   0   SMSESSIONMTySTv50SShcdl5y9C7TChWfGP5xbsW4P13QQLR6kkJyYtfVnx4q!574440962
bill4u.orange.co.il FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  5rYLMT1QKTxTLhNTy0gkNGr4zGfhtlky9pxy20gHL1Ns65TgsCHy!-2121300565
```

Does it indicate some problems?

My CURL request only contains the SMSESSION value and not the JSESSIONID value.

This is thew request I got from live headers:

```
JSESSIONID=MTdLyyl2yGV1GnQW1LwlLQHPz0gPg8nCFpzDRkhQY01fLpTGGWnh!574440962; __utma=242473949.127100127.1288950781.1288950781.1288957650.2; __utmc=242473949; __utmz=242473949.1288957650.2.2.utmcsr=bill4u.orange.co.il|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/action/mainAction; SMSESSION=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; __utmv=242473949.|1=VisitorsStatus=LoggedInClient=1,; __utmb=242473949.16.10.1288957650
```

And this is from the CURL request:

```
SMSESSION=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; JSESSIONID=MTySTv50SShcdl5y9C7TChWfGP5xbsW4P13QQLR6kkJyYtfVnx4q!574440962
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: it seems that the JSESSIONID value is being generated on the fly when I hit the new url.

Answer (score 7):

Have you checked the [curl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) (see section 10 here)

> Curl has a full blown cookie parsing
>   engine built-in that comes to use if
>   you  want to reconnect to a server and
>   use cookies that were stored from a 
>   previous connection (or handicrafted
>   manually to fool the server into 
>   believing you had a previous
>   connection). To use previously stored
>   cookies,  you run curl like:
>
> ```
>     curl --cookie stored_cookies_in_file http://www.cookiesite.com
> ```
>
> Curl's
>   "cookie engine" gets enabled when you
>   use the --cookie option. If you  only
>   want curl to understand received
>   cookies, use --cookie with a file that
>   doesn't exist. Example, if you want to
>   let curl understand cookies from a
>   page  and follow a location (and thus
>   possibly send back cookies it
>   received), you  can invoke it like:
>
> ```
>     curl --cookie nada --location http://www.cookiesite.com
> ```
>
> Curl has
>   the ability to read and write cookie
>   files that use the same file  format
>   that Netscape and Mozilla do. It is a
>   convenient way to share cookies 
>   between browsers and automatic
>   scripts. The --cookie (-b) switch
>   automatically  detects if a given file
>   is such a cookie file and parses it,
>   and by using the  --cookie-jar (-c)
>   option you'll make curl write a new
>   cookie file at the end of  an
>   operation:
>
> ```
>     curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt http://www.cookiesite.com
> ```

Comment: I'm using those:

curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);

Answer (score 7):

Try this syntax to get curl to pass the jsessionid cookie and place the fetched data in a textfile:

```
curl --cookie "JSESSIONID=5rYLMT1QKTxTLhNTy0gkNGr4zGfhtlky9pxy20gHL1Ns65TgsCHy!-2121300565; path=/" -o jj.txt "http://bill4u.orange.co.il"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I did the following based on the messages above and it worked

curl --cookie-jar /tmp/storecookie.txt  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "header2:value" -d '{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}' -k  https://someurl.com

USE the Jsessionid from the /tmp/storecookie.txt and feed to the below

curl --cookie "JSESSIONID=34f0ef966c3b3a79bddbd1c406775716" -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "header2:value" -o /tmp/response.txt -k  https://someurl.com

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30618031)